# Replace values from a column for vector value

Tags: r, vector, replace

I have a vector `x` which has 3 levels and 10 values, and a vector `y` which has also 3 levels vut only 3 values.
`x <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C")`
`y <- c("Red","Blue","Green")`

I Want to swap the `A`s from `x` for `Red` in `y[,1]`, then `B`s from `x` for `Blue` in `y[,2]` and the same for the last one.

I thaught in using the `replace` function as
`z <- replace(x, c("A","B", "C"), c("Red","Blue","Green"))`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x1<-merge(data.frame(A=x),data.frame(A=c('A','B','C'),B=c("Red,"Blue","Green")),by='A')[,2]`

did that and do the trick

Answer (score 3):

I think closest to what you want will be using `dplyr::recode`:

```
x <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C")
map <- c(A = "Red", B = "Blue", C = "Green")
res <- dplyr::recode(x, !!!map)
```

or `plyr::mapvalues`:

```
res <- plyr::mapvalues(
  x, 
  from = c("A","B", "C"), 
  to = c("Red","Blue","Green")
)
```

Comment: Which is translatable to `map[x]` in base R.

Answer (score 1):

A base R method would be to convert `x` to `factor` and then `integer` to get numerical indexes which can be used to subset `y`.

```
y[as.integer(factor(x, levels = unique(x)))]
#[1] "Red"   "Red"   "Red"   "Red"   "Blue"  "Blue"  "Green" "Green" "Green" "Green"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr:

```
x <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C")
y <- c("Red","Blue","Green")

z <- case_when(x == 'A' ~ 'Red', x == 'B' ~ 'Blue', x == 'C' ~ 'Green')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library `stringr`

```
library(stringr)

z <- str_replace_all(x, c("A"="Red", "B"="Blue", "C"="Green"))
```

The reason your code is not working is because the `replace`function wants in second argument a list of indexes and not the string values to be replaced.